# Android client is able to connect to My OpenVPN server in azure but unable to connect from my asus router (RT-AC88U)

Tags: wireless-router, openvpn, azure

I setup OpenVPN Access Server 2.5.0 in Azure VM (BYOD Free license) using the guide here. I'm able to connect from Android client. But my router (ASUS RT-AC88U) is not able to connect using same .ovpn config and credentials. When i click on activate button, loading icon is spinning forever.

Router Log:

Jul  3 21:51:29 vpnclient5[11291]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]

Jul  3 21:51:29 vpnclient5[11291]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]104.211.XXX.XXX:1194

Jul  3 21:51:29 vpnclient5[11291]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]104.211.XXX.XXX:1194, sid=07ece48a 9341382f

Jul  3 21:52:29 vpnclient5[11291]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

Jul  3 21:52:29 vpnclient5[11291]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

Jul  3 21:52:29 vpnclient5[11291]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting

Comment: Where is your guide link?

Comment: You mean router manual? https://www.asus.com/sg/Networking/RT-AC88U/HelpDesk_Manual/